# What'd be a good SEd trick to list the properties of all X input devices?

Tags: devices, sed, xinput

A list of X input devices is returned using the command `xinput --list` and the properties of an input device are listed using a command of the form `xinput --list-props "device name"`. How could SEd be used to get a printout of all of the input devices *and* all of their respective properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--list-props also accepts the numeric id, so

```
xinput --list | sed -n 's/.*id=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' | xargs xinput --list-props
```

Or, thanks to @steeldriver

```
xinput --list --id-only | xargs xinput --list-props
```

Comment: At least on my system, `xinput --list` accepts a further switch `--id-only`, which eliminates the need for `sed` altogether

Comment: Great! Thank you both for your solutions. They are quite handy commands to have.

Comment: It occurred to me that `grep -oP '(?<=id=)\d+'` would be more concise than the sed command